# Setting a different diff tool dynamically at git diff calling

Tags: git, git-diff

Is it possible to set a different diff tool dynamically when `git diff` is being called, even using shell variables?

I don't mean changing (persisting) git-config configurations, but changing it at "calling time", like as:

```
$ git diff oldbranch --diff-tool=path-to-my-diff-tool
$ GIT_DIFF_TOOL=path git diff oldbranch
$ export GIT_DIFF_TOOL=path; git diff oldbranch
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe not exactly, but you can get the exact same effect.  (Maybe that *is* "exactly". :-) )  Instead of changing the persistent local configuration with `git config diff.tool sometool`, just change the configuration used for *this Git command* with, e.g., `git -c diff.tool=sometool difftool ...`.

Any change you *could* make permanently with `git config name value`, you can make temporarily with `git -c name=value`, for the duration of one Git command.

Edit: note that `git difftool` itself has a `-t tool` argument, so this particular example is a bit silly.  I'm just using it here to show how the `-c name=value` trick works.

Comment: I've never used `-c` flag before. Just tried it with `git diff`and `git difftool`, it's worked only with `difftool`. However I'm new to `difftool`, didn't know it existed before and docs said there is also an exclusive argument `-tool`, both ways worked with `difftool`: `git difftool -tool=yourtool -- file.c`

Comment: torek's solution is of course excellent, and I might say something horribly wrong out of ignorance but.... isn't `git difftool --tool='sometool' <branch>` the basic option for that? Or is there a difference?

Comment: @RomainValeri I don't actually use `git difftool` myself, but yes, it's not really the best example here because it has `-t` / `--tool`. I was just using it as an example of where `-c name=value` has the same effect as configuring `name` to `value`.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding it here for memory, since it also technically answers the question.

```
git difftool --tool='sometool' <branch>
# or
git difftool -t 'sometool' <branch>
```

See [--tool](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool#git-difftool---toollttoolgt) (doc).